# How to fix white screen error in Google Flutter RandomWords Widget?

Tags: android, macos, dart, widget, flutter

Right so, I have been trying out Google Flutter at work with MAC and Android Studio and I was doing the Write Your First Flutter App from https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/#step-1-create-the-starting-flutter-app
and I got all the way to STEP 3 perfectly and when I wrote the code for STEP 4 I just got a white screen in the Android Emulator. Having given up comparing the code and seeing it was identical I clicked on STEP 4's Problem's link: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Sfshaza/d6f9460a04d3a429eb6ac0b0f07da564/raw/34fe240f4122435c871bb737708ee0357741801c/main.dart
and copied the same code into my Android Studio lib/main.dart code. When I reloaded the emulator the screen went white and in the Android Studio console I got this error code:

```
I/flutter ( 5686): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'SceneBuilder' has no instance method 'pushPhysicalShape' with matching arguments.
W/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]( 5686): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=930656, downTime=930648, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
D/EGL_emulation( 5686): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8b84720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9477b080)
I/FlutterActivityDelegate( 5686): onResume setting current activity to this
D/EGL_emulation( 5686): eglCreateContext: 0xa61fd0e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation( 5686): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa61fd0e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xb218b8f0)
E/eglCodecCommon( 5686): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon( 5686): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon( 5686): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon( 5686): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
D/EGL_emulation( 5686): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa61fd0e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa66ff770)
D/EGL_emulation( 5686): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8b84720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x9477b080)    
I/flutter ( 5686): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5686): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
I/flutter ( 5686): Class 'SceneBuilder' has no instance method 'pushPhysicalShape' with matching arguments.
I/flutter ( 5686): Receiver: Instance of 'SceneBuilder  
I/flutter ( 5686): Tried calling: pushPhysicalShape(color: Instance of 'Color', elevation: 0.0, path: Instance of
I/flutter ( 5686): 'Path', shadowColor: Instance of 'Color')
I/flutter ( 5686): Found: pushPhysicalShape({Path path, double elevation, Color color}) => void
I/flutter ( 5686): 
I/flutter ( 5686): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 5686): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
I/flutter ( 5686): #1      PhysicalModelLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:797)
I/flutter ( 5686): #2      ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:422)
I/flutter ( 5686): #3      OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:510)
I/flutter ( 5686): #4      ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:422)
I/flutter ( 5686): #5      OffsetLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:510)
I/flutter ( 5686): #6      ContainerLayer.addChildrenToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:422)
I/flutter ( 5686): #7      TransformLayer.addToScene (package:flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart:638)
I/flutter ( 5686): #8      RenderView.compositeFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:173)
I/flutter ( 5686): #9      BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:273)
I/flutter ( 5686): #10     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:622)
I/flutter ( 5686): #11     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208)
I/flutter ( 5686): #12     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990)
I/flutter ( 5686): #13     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930)
I/flutter ( 5686): #14     BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751)
I/flutter ( 5686): #16     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/timer_impl.dart:382)
I/flutter ( 5686): #17     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/timer_impl.dart:416)
I/flutter ( 5686): #18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
I/flutter ( 5686): (elided one frame from package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 5686): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Any idea what it might be? Could it be that the path of my flutter directory is incorrect? or could the flutter tutorial be wrong? Thanks

Comment: That gist runs fine for me. What happens if you `flutter run` from the command line? Check you are on flutter 0.2.8. Check `flutter doctor`. Try using Visual Studio Code instead of Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks Richard, when I run "flutter run" or "flutter doctor" it says "Command not found" and when I put "PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH" it lets me do flutter doctor but not flutter run. I'm pretty sure I haven't set the path correctly. I'm new to Mac so I don't know about that

Comment: Update: I just reinstalled flutter and put the same path code and it all works now. Wonder if it will work next time I turn on the pc or if I will have to reinstall and put the same path